# Parse Elixir Terms From A String

Tags: elixir

Erlang has a facility for parsing Erlang terms from a string. This has the advantage of avoiding dynamic code execution (ie not trusting user input), but allows the user to enter any valid literal values.

See: http://www.erlang.org/faq/how_do_i.html#idp32770608

Does Elixir allow for something similar to this? Can I easily accept a string and attempt to parse it?

Ideally it would look something like:

```
str = "{:foo, %{bar: true}, nil}"
Elixir.parse_term(str) # => {:foo, %{bar: true}, nil}
```

Comment: Maybe you could use `Code.string_to_quoted/2` and then filter everything except literal values.

Comment: I agree with Patrick here, that seems like the best way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Elixir pattern matching this is easy peasy:

```
defmodule ParseTerm do
  def parse(str) when is_binary(str)do
    case str |> Code.string_to_quoted do
      {:ok, terms} -> {:ok, _parse(terms)}
      {:error, _}  -> {:invalid_terms}
    end
  end

  # atomic terms
  defp _parse(term) when is_atom(term), do: term
  defp _parse(term) when is_integer(term), do: term
  defp _parse(term) when is_float(term), do: term
  defp _parse(term) when is_binary(term), do: term

  defp _parse([]), do: []
  defp _parse([h|t]), do: [_parse(h) | _parse(t)]

  defp _parse({a, b}), do: {_parse(a), _parse(b)}
  defp _parse({:"{}", _place, terms}) do
    terms
    |> Enum.map(&_parse/1)
    |> List.to_tuple
  end

  defp _parse({:"%{}", _place, terms}) do
    for {k, v} <- terms, into: %{}, do: {_parse(k), _parse(v)}
  end

  defp _parse({_term_type, _place, terms}), do: terms # to ignore functions and operators
end
```

Use it like this:

```
iex(1)> ParseTerm.parse "%{1=>:a, :q=>:z, :w => [1,2, 1.618, {1,2, %{a: \"1.2\" } }] }"
{:ok, %{1 => :a, :q => :z, :w => [1, 2, 1.618, {1, 2, %{a: "1.2"}}]}}
```

Comment: This is a really good start to the idea that I had, but it behaves a bit oddly in a few cases.

    ParseTerm.parse "File.read!(\"/etc/passwd\")" # => {:ok, ["/etc/passwd"]}

Comment: In other words if the string contains non-literal terms I think it should raise an error rather than trying to ignore those terms, but this is definitely heading the right direction. I'll try to put together an example of what I'm thinking of.

Comment: what do you think of this implementation? https://gist.github.com/mmmries/b657c77845b07ee8cd34 Basically I got rid of the wildcard match that was ignoring terms and used a try-catch to detect if unsupported terms were encountered so it could return an `{:error, message}` tuple in that case

Comment: Yeah, I know - I didn't want to use `throw` in this code (I know J.Armstrong said it's ok to use it in those situations http://joearms.github.io/2015/01/08/Some_Performance-Measurements-On-Maps.html) but I think the code would smell. And adding semi-complex error propagation routine was out of the problem's scope.

Comment: I think your implementation is definitely sufficient for the question as posed. I'll try to cleanup up my error propagation a bit because the code in my gist smells a bit for me as well.